# Making an Ajax form from an Ajax request in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The client is making a request to the server.
I need to take part of that request, and make the form button work with Ajax.

This piece of code works perfectly for links:

```
var pagination_render = function() {
    var pagination = $('.pagination a');
    pagination.each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(event) {
            load_server(this.href, '.houseindex');
            return false;
        });
    });
};
pagination_render();
```

I tried numerous things for making the Ajax button work, and this is one of the tries:

```
var contact_user = function () {
    $('.expanded').find('#submit').each(function() {
        $(this).unbind('click');
    });

    $('.expanded').each(function() {
        $(this).find('#submit').click(function(event) {
            form_submit($(this).parent(), '.contactuser .msg');
            return false;
        });
    });
}
```

Whenever there is a successful Ajax call, it goes through all of the expanded items, and then binds a click event.

Now, sometimes this code works, and sometimes it doesn't.. When it doesn't work, it disables other events (toggle links) I have set up.
It seems as if I need to wait a few ms for it to load the component into the DOM.. Do I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I get that when you call `contact_user` you:

1. First unbind any previous binded click events from the submit button. I see one possible problem there and is that you are looking for an id of `#submit`. You should only have one id in a single page. Therefore you only need to use `$('#submit').each(...)` or if you have several submit buttons in the page either use a class if there are several submit buttons inside an `.expanded` item or just use `$('.expanded :submit')`
2. Adding a custom event when clicking the submit button. Same thing, you can simplify this by `$('.expanded :submit')` or if you truly only have one button with an id of `submit` (quite confusing). Go with `$('#submit')`.

In conclusion:

```
var contact_user = function(){
   $('.expanded :submit').unbind('click');
   $('.expanded :submit').click(function(){
      form_submit($(this).parent(), '.contactuser .msg');
      return false;
   });
};
```

the `:submit` selector will select all `<input type="submit" />`.

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you.
The problem, apparently, was in a duplicate call for a function.

I like the idea of using :submit, forgot it's a possibility with jQuery.